# Variables of scripts go away with autocmd?

Tags: vim, autocmd, vundle

I tried this in `.vimrc` (which uses `vundle`):

```
autocmd FileType python Bundle 'ervandew/supertab'
```

and `'ervandew/supertab'` also lists in 'BundleList` in a python file. It doesn't work. I don't know why. Maybe my autocmd command was wrong?

I suspect the assignments are going away. When I do just `Bundle 'ervandew/supertab'`, I can see variables in vim. For example `:let SuperTabMappingForward` shows `SuperTabMappingForward <tab>`. But with autocmd, I get `E121: Undefined variable: SuperTabMappingForward`. I get the same when I put `Bundle 'ervandew/supertab'` in `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`

My vim knowledge in limited!

Answer (score 2):

The `:Bundle` command is meant to be put into your `~/.vimrc`, which is executed *before all other initializations*. Those won't run automatically when you later issue the `:Bundle` command.

So, you'll need to add at least

```
:autocmd FileType python runtime! plugin/supertab.vim
```

to run the plugin initialization. (And then, those variables should show up, too!)

#### critique

I'd recommend against such dynamic plugin loads. Do you do them to speed up Vim startup? Do you really only want a general-purpose plugin like SuperTab loaded for Python files?!

Comment: I want to use `jedi-vim` and `supertab` for `python` files and `YouCompleteMe` for everything else (which includes `supertab`).